# C Programming: wrong output?

Tags: c

Hy everybody, so I'm trying to solve this problem

Write a C program that computes the distance a projectile travels before hitting the ground (i.e. its range), the time it takes for the projectile to hit the ground, and the maximum height of the projectile in flight, given the angle that it is shot into the air, and its initial velocity (speed) when it is launched. We will assume that the ground is flat and that the only force present is gravity (no air resistance, etc.).

```
Maximum height: h=pow(v*sin(θ),2)/2*g;
Time in air: t = (2*v*sin(θ))/g;
Range: r = (2*pow(v,2)*sin(θ)*cos(θ))/g;



θ = angle that the projectile is launched (in whole degrees)
v = initial velocity of the projectile (in meters/second)
g = acceleration due to gravity = 9.8 meters/second2
```

Now I don't know why I get negative results. I suppose that I used the wrong declaration syntax or maybe I give wrong input for the angle and the initial velocity, or it's because the divisions are rounded.. can someone help me figure out what is the right way to solve this problem? (I'm new to C Programming and I want to learn)

Comment: I would only work on that assignment if I could replace "projectile" with "teacher" just so that the playing field is more level for the targets.

Comment: Trig functions in `math.h` take arguments in radians, not degrees.

Comment: Do you get the right answer when you do the calculation by hand? Compare each piece of the formula in your program with a corresponding hand calculation. Narrow it down to the place that differs. Narrow it further. Eventually you will narrow it to one function. Read the documentation for that function.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? For some specific input, what is the expected and actual output? And you do remember that [`<math.h>` function `sin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sin) expects its angle in radians?

Comment: `h=pow(v*sin(θ),2)/(2*g);`

Answer (score 0):

The correct formulas are as given below

```
Maximum height: h=pow(v*sin(θ*M_PI/180),2)/(2*g);
Time in air: t = (2*v*sin(θ*M_PI/180))/g;
Range: r = (2*pow(v,2)*sin(θ*M_PI/180)*cos(θ*M_PI/180))/g;
```

You can even reduce Range formula to `pow(v,2)*sin(2*θ*M_PI/180)/g`

as `sin(2θ) = 2*sin(θ)*cos(θ)`

From the comments by @Mat, @BLUEPIXY and @Sanhadrin

Comment: Most implementations of <math.h> define M_PI, you know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, I didn't know that sin & cos use radian. I had to rewrite the whole thing and this is how it looks now:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void){
    int theta;
    float h, g=9.8, t, r, v;

    printf("Type a value for the angle that the projectile is launched (in whole degrees): ");
    scanf("%d",&theta);
    printf("Type a value for the initial velocity of the projectile (in m/s): ");
    scanf("%f",&v);


    theta = theta*M_PI/180;
    h = pow(v*sin(theta),2)/(2*g);
    t = (2*v*sin(theta))/g;
    r = (2*pow(v,2)*sin(theta)*cos(theta))/g;

    printf("The maximum height is %f m, the time it takes for the projectile to hit the ground is %f s and it's range is %f m\n", h, t, r);

    return 0;
}
```

And when I run it:

```
Type a value for the angle that the projectile is launched (in whole degrees): 110
Type a value for the initial velocity of the projectile (in m/s): 6.2
The maximum height is 1.388691 m, the time it takes for the projectile to hit the ground is 1.064718 s and it's range is 3.566673 m
```